# Geowebcache REST 404's

Tags: geoserver, rest, geowebcache

I'm running Geoserver 2.1.3 (SVN 16668) and am trying to get REST working with GeoWebCache. I've got :8080/geoserver/rest working correctly, and am able to interact with that side of things. However, :8080/geowebcache doesn't exist. I'm told that the only two contexts that exist are /javadocs and /geoserver.

I understand that there is such a thing as a REST api for geowebcache. How do I get to it? Is there some additional plugin that I need to download for GeoServer before it becomes accessible, or something of that sort? I haven't been able to find anything on the net about someone just missing the REST section of GeoWebCache. The rest of it works fine. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need additional plugins to get GeoWebCache working. All you need is navigate  to GeoWebCache settings page, and check `Enable WMS Integration`. You can then confirm that it is working by navigating to the GeoWebCache Demo page `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/demo` for localhost on port 8080. Refer to [this page](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/config.html) for more info.

From your own pages, you can access the layers the same way you'd access WMS layers, making sure you specify the `TILE_SIZE` parameter.

I don't think you need the REST API for this. If you want to manipulate the workspace, data stores, etc, from another application, say Java or C# or PHP, then you'll need the REST API. Refer to [this page](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-api.html) for more info.

Comment: Ahh, yeah you're right...the URL is different..the docs at http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/rest/layers.html say it should be :8080/geowebcache/rest/layers/ but that's obviouslly not correct. Whelp, not the first time Geoserver's docs have led me wrong.

Comment: lightstrike, the GeoServer docs are open source, feel free to provide patches to improve them: https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/master/doc

Comment: Sent. I'm not sure if I did it correctly, honestly, as I've never used github before, but I've sent a pull request to the geowebcache project.

Comment: " but I've sent a pull request". What do you mean by this? May be if you explain what you are trying to achieve, it'll be easier to assist.